# Linux OpenSuse c++ compiler issue. (unable to initialise decompress status for section debugger)

Tags: c++, compiler-errors, opensuse

I have installed Linux opensuse on vmware and want to compile C++ programs in the terminal. I installed the gcc c++ compiler from here

https://software.opensuse.org/package/gcc-c++

But I am still not able to compile and getting some kind of error even while compiling simple hello world code:

```
#include <iostream>
 using namespace std;

int main() {
    cout << "Hello, World!";
    return 0; }
```

This is the error i am getting

> ```
> vaibhaw@linux-xn99:~/CPP> vi helloworld.cpp vaibhaw@linux-xn99:~/CPP>
> g++ helloworld.cpp
> /usr/lib64/gcc/x86_64-suse-linux/8/../../../../x86_64-suse-linux/bin/ld:
> /usr/lib64/gcc/x86_64-suse-linux/8/libgcc.a(_muldi3.o): unable to
> initialize decompress status for section .debug_info
> /usr/lib64/gcc/x86_64-suse-linux/8/../../../../x86_64-suse-linux/bin/ld:
> /usr/lib64/gcc/x86_64-suse-linux/8/libgcc.a(_muldi3.o): unable to
> initialize decompress status for section .debug_info
> /usr/lib64/gcc/x86_64-suse-linux/8/../../../../x86_64-suse-linux/bin/ld:
> /usr/lib64/gcc/x86_64-suse-linux/8/libgcc.a(_muldi3.o): unable to
> initialize decompress status for section .debug_info
> /usr/lib64/gcc/x86_64-suse-linux/8/../../../../x86_64-suse-linux/bin/ld:
> /usr/lib64/gcc/x86_64-suse-linux/8/libgcc.a(_muldi3.o): unable to
> initialize decompress status for section .debug_info
> /usr/lib64/gcc/x86_64-suse-linux/8/../../../../x86_64-suse-linux/bin/ld:
> /usr/lib64/gcc/x86_64-suse-linux/8/libgcc.a(_muldi3.o): unable to
> initialize decompress status for section .debug_info
> /usr/lib64/gcc/x86_64-suse-linux/8/../../../../x86_64-suse-linux/bin/ld:
> /usr/lib64/gcc/x86_64-suse-linux/8/libgcc.a(_muldi3.o): unable to
> initialize decompress status for section .debug_info
> /usr/lib64/gcc/x86_64-suse-linux/8/../../../../x86_64-suse-linux/bin/ld:
> /usr/lib64/gcc/x86_64-suse-linux/8/libgcc.a(_muldi3.o): unable to
> initialize decompress status for section .debug_info
> /usr/lib64/gcc/x86_64-suse-linux/8/../../../../x86_64-suse-linux/bin/ld:
> /usr/lib64/gcc/x86_64-suse-linux/8/libgcc.a(_muldi3.o): unable to
> initialize decompress status for section .debug_info
> ```

Comment: I have edited the post and added the code and error message

Comment: same here on openSUSE Leap 42.3, getting absolutely the same error messages

Answer (score 0):

A simple 'zypper in gcc-c++' would have pulled in all require packages from the installation and update repositories. No need to use the software.opensuse.org website.